# Magento 1.8 Alpha1 CE Sample Data

Tags: catalog, indexing

Is there a version of Magento's sample data that works with the 1.8 CE Alpha 1 release?  I just installed the package and I'm seeing errors when re-indexing.

```
$ php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
Catalog URL Rewrites index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_URL_KEY_STORE_ID_VALUE'' in /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#7 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php(546): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('catalog_product...', Array)
#8 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(374): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->saveProductAttribute(Object(Varien_Object), 'url_key')
#9 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(562): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshProductRewrite(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Varien_Object))
#10 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(255): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshProductRewrites('1')
#11 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(248): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites('1')
#12 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Url.php(257): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites()
#13 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url->reindexAll()
#14 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_URL_KEY_STORE_ID_VALUE'' in /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php(546): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('catalog_product...', Array)
#7 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(374): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->saveProductAttribute(Object(Varien_Object), 'url_key')
#8 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(562): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshProductRewrite(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Varien_Object))
#9 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(255): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshProductRewrites('1')
#10 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(248): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites('1')
#11 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Url.php(257): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites()
#12 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url->reindexAll()
#13 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /path/to/magento1point8alpha1.dev/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

Failing working sample data, is there a known method to surgically fix this problem manually in the database?

Or is this a result of some alpha-ish bugs that'll be fixed in a future release? (Tangent: Where **should** the unwashed masses report bugs these days?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe Vinai Kopp found a solution for this - https://gist.github.com/Vinai/5451584

Any site with duplicate url_keys will be affected. The 1.6.1 sample data is but one example. See the gist for a bit more background.

Answer (score 2):

First reported here...
http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=14940

See the comments for the full debug with magento sample data and solution, and which product is affected exactly.